# oracle conditional in clause

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to do conditional in clause in oracle when one of the in parameters can be null

example:

Replace the pseudo code with single oracle query

query will fetch employees updated by job_id or parent_job_id 

only if parent_job_id is not null

```
fetch_employees(_job_id,_parent_job_id)
{
if(_parent_job_id==null){
    return result of  select * from employee where job_id = _job_id
}
else {
    return result of  select * from employee where job_id in( _job_id,_parent_job_id)
 }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
fetch_employees(_job_id,_parent_job_id);

select e.*
from employee e
where (_parent_job_id is null and job_id = _job_id) or
      (_parent_job_id is not null and job_id in( _job_id, _parent_job_id) )
```

Actually, the `NULL` is allowed in `in`.  So, you could just do:

```
fetch_employees(_job_id,_parent_job_id);

select e.*
from employee e
where job_id in( _job_id, _parent_job_id);
```

Comment: sorry I forgot NULL is allowed in in but query should not bring in nulls

Comment: What do you mean?  Nothing matches the `NULL` value, so it will not affect the results.

Comment: I don't want to bring employee where job_id is null, I think the first query will work, correct?

Comment: @user648026 . . . Neither query will return a row where the `job_id` is `NULL`.  Like I said, `NULL` fails the `in` comparison, so it will not be returned.

Comment: So this [ job_id in( _job_id, _parent_job_id) ] will not return job_id that are nulls??  I didn't know that!       THANK YOU